# How to compile all files with the extension *.server.ts only?

Tags: typescript, atom-editor, tsc

Suppose we have the following files:

```
/mymodule1/
   main.server.ts
   main.client.ts

/mymodule2/
   main.server.ts
   main.client.ts
```

How do we only compile all *.server.ts files but leave the *.client.ts files untouched ?

I tried something like this in my tsconfig.json but it fails:

> tsconfig.json, when using **tsc cli**:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "**/*.server.ts"
    ]
}
```

[edit]

or something like this:

> tsconfig.json, when using **Atom**:

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "target": "es5",
            "module": "commonjs",
            "sourceMap": true
        },
        "filesGlob": [
            "**/*.server.ts" //seams to work, but Atom complains that the other files are not added to the compile context.
        ],
        "exclude": [
           "**/*.client.ts", //fails, as well as in files
            "typings",
            "node_modules"
        ]

    }
```

Is there an *filesExcludeGlob* ?

Answer (score 0):

> tsconfig.json

tsconfig.json doesn't support *globs* in `files` natively.

That said atom-typescript supports it https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md#filesglob , grunt-ts supports it : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts

So in your you cannot do it natively with just `tsc`.

> Is there an filesExcludeGlob

You can use just negation:

```
"filesGlob":[
  "**/*.server.ts",
  "!**/**.client.ts",
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
I should have mentioned that I have tried it with Atom and tsc cli. 
Do you like to provide a working example please? Which tool doesn't matter.